# vert.x: How do you correctly send a post request?

Tags: java, unit-testing, post, reactive-programming, vert.x

I have [vert.x](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vert.x/info) app-server with simplest authorization, which has some route like this:

```
router.post("/user/sign").handler(this::userSignIn);
```

While I'm doing this from the [GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/user-interface/info), it works fine.

But I want to create [Unit-Test](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unit-testing/info) for this action.
The code I did:

```
@Test
public void testServerUserRegister(TestContext context) {
  HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();
  HttpClientRequest request = client.post("user/sign", response -> {
  System.out.println("Some callback " + response.statusCode());
  });

  String body = "{'username':'www','password':'www'}";
  request.putHeader("content-length", "1000");
  request.putHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  request.write(body);
  request.end();
}
```

When I start this test: `mvn test`

I see results but:

1- I don't see any String like "Some callback..."

2- I'm getting a `RejectedExecutionException`:

```
вер. 16, 2016 4:29:20 PM io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientImpl
  SEVERE: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
  вер. 16, 2016 4:29:20 PM io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe invokeLater
  WARNING: Can't invoke task later as EventLoop rejected it
  java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated

  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor
     .reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:707)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor
     .addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:299)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor
     .execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:687)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe
     .invokeLater(AbstractChannel.java:826)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe
     .deregister(AbstractChannel.java:656)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe
     .fireChannelInactiveAndDeregister(AbstractChannel.java:626)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe
     .close(AbstractChannel.java:600)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.closeAll(NioEventLoop.java:576)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:361)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2
     .run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the call to `request.end()`, the JUnit test exits and your Vert.x instance is closed (hence the RejectedExecutionException).

Remember that Vert.x APIs are asynchronous. Have a look at the [Vert.x Unit section about asynchronous testing](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/unit/TestContext.html#async--).

What you should do is something like:

```java
@Test
public void testServerUserRegister(TestContext context) {
  // Get an async object to control the completion of the test
  Async async = context.async();
  HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();
  HttpClientRequest request = client.post("user/sign", response -> {
    // You may want to check response code here
    // to either complete or fail the test
    async.complete();
    System.out.println("Some callback " + response.statusCode());
  });

  String body = "{'username':'www','password':'www'}";
  request.putHeader("content-length", "1000");
  request.putHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  request.write(body);
  request.end();
}
```

Comment: when you send content of type `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` you might want to send a body formatted this way: `"username=www&password=www"`